# how to access files from servlet on server side in JSP application in Tomcat server

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat7

We are developing a small JSP application using Eclipse for tomcat server. This application has a servlet `DisplayQuotes` in the package `org.svist.stockquotes`. This servlet requires to load two javascript files from the server, yes javascript files. I tried to keep these files in `js` folder (at the same level as the `src` folder) and tried to load them through the relative path `"js/jquyer.js"`, `"js/env-rhino.js"`. But it was always failing to load them. After deploying the .war file on the tomcat, i got the same error. Can anyone please help?

I am using tomcat 7 and JDK 6 build 24.

Answer (score 0):

put it in public web domain. at the same level of your `WEB-INF` dir. and then refer it

```
---------WEB-INF
         |
         js
          ---------
                   |your js files
```

---

```
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/env-rhino.js" />
```

Comment: josh, I am doing as you suggested. When I tried to build from Eclipse, Eclipse is getting stuck with the message "Validating StockQuotes/WebContent/WEB-INF/js". Eclipse is taking forever to finish that job.

Comment: its not `Validating StockQuotes/WebContent/WEB-INF/js` but `Validating StockQuotes/WebContent/js`